# xamarin.android permgen space error

Tags: android, xamarin.android, permgen

I am creating an android app in Xamarin 3. The app runs perfectly but gives an error when i try to view the .axml designer. This is the error:

> "The layout could not be loaded: PermGen space"

I know that it is a Java.Lang.OutofMemory error but not quite sure how to solve it in my xamarin project. I am also using Visual Studio with the Xamarin plugin. How do I get this to go away? I understand that increasing the size might be a solution, but not sure how to do that - as all the examples on the web are in Java with Eclipse. Thanks to all those that take the time to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restarted Visual Studio and this error is gone for now.

Comment: ugghhhh. This should not be a thing.